# How to use dynamic TextField Controller inside ExpansionTile Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Being new to *Flutter*, I have created a ExpansionTile (see below screenshot) and have added `EditField` as a *Child*.
Here `ExpansioTile` and comment `EditField` is created dynamically based on server response.
Inside each `ExpansionTile` there will be multiple `TextFields`

Now how do I add `TextFieldController` dynamically and get all values upon button click?

[image: Application form screenshot]

**ExpansionTile Code**

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: _fetchQuestions(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
                }
                else  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return new Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        controller: _pageController,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data[0].auditAreas.length,
                        onPageChanged: (int index) {
                          print('@@ on page changed $index');
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          print('@@ index '+index.toString());

                          List<QuestionGroups> listQuestionsGrp = snapshot.data[0].auditAreas[index].questionGroups;
                          print('@@ question grp list size == '+listQuestionsGrp.length.toString());

                          List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
                          for (int i=0; i<listQuestionsGrp.length; i++){

                            bloc.newFields();
                            List<Widget> listItemWidgets = new List<Widget>();

                            // below list(listAuditQues) is used to get the questions from question groups
                            List<AuditQuestions> listAuditQues = listQuestionsGrp[i].auditQuestions;
                            for (int j=0; j<listAuditQues.length; j++){

                              print('@ audit question id == '+listAuditQues[j].auditQuestionId.toString());

                              // _mapController.map(listAuditQues[j].auditQuestionId, _textController);
                              // _controllers.add(TextEditingController());
                              List<AuditQuestionAnswers> listAuditQuestAns = listAuditQues[j].auditQuestionAnswers;
                              print('@@ list of question and answers used for radio buttons == '+listAuditQuestAns.length.toString());

                              List<Widget> listTitleOfRadioButtons = new List<Widget>();
                              for (int k=0; k<listAuditQuestAns.length; k++){

                                // here have to get the list of radio button text and append below inside the column
                                List<AuditQuestionAnswerOptionParameters> listQuesAnsParameter = listAuditQuestAns[k].auditQuestionAnswerOptionParameters;
                                print('@@ list question answer list size == '+listQuesAnsParameter.length.toString());
                                List<Widget> listRadioButtons = new List<Widget>();

                                for (int m=0; m<listQuesAnsParameter.length; m++){
                                  listRadioButtons.add(
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          new Radio(value: 0, groupValue: null, onChanged: null, materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,),
                                          new Text(listQuesAnsParameter[m].answerOptionParameterTitle,style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 12.0
                                          ))
                                        ],
                                      )
                                  );
                                }

                                listTitleOfRadioButtons.add(
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 4.0, 0.0, 4.0),
                                          child: Text(listAuditQuestAns[k].auditEntityTitle,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.5),),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: listRadioButtons,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                );
                              }

                              // Here adding expansion item content
                              listItemWidgets.add(
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Row(
                                        // mainAxisAlignment: message.author == username ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        //this will determine if the message should be displayed left or right
                                          children: [
                                            Flexible(
                                              //Wrapping the container with flexible widget
                                              child: Container(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Flexible(
                                                        //We only want to wrap the text message with flexible widget
                                                          child: Container(
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                listAuditQues[j].title,
                                                              )
                                                          )
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                            )

                                          ]
                                      ),

                                      Column(
                                        children: listTitleOfRadioButtons
                                      ),

                                      Container(
                                        height: 80,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                        child: new ConstrainedBox(
                                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                            maxHeight: 80.0,
                                          ),
                                          child: new Scrollbar(
                                            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                              reverse: true,
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: 80.0,
                                                child: new TextFormField(
                                                 // controller: _controllers[j],
                                                  maxLines: 60,
                                                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                    labelText: "Comment",
                                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderSide:
                                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0.8)),
                                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderSide:
                                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0.8)),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      new Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: (){
                                                print('@@ index of pager $index');
                                                print('@@ index of main lopp $i');
                                                print('@@ index of lopp $j');
                                              },
                                              child: new Icon(Icons.camera_alt,
                                                  size: 22.0, color: Colors.black),
                                            ),
                                            new Icon(Icons.attach_file,
                                                size: 22.0, color: Colors.black),
                                            new Text("(4)", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                        child: Divider(height: 4.0,color: Colors.black),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                              );
                            }

                            // Main Title of expansion list adding here
                            list.add(customExpansionTile.ExpansionTile(
                                headerBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                iconColor: Colors.black,
                                title: Text(listQuestionsGrp[i].title, style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0
                                )),
                              children: listItemWidgets
                            ));

                          }
                          return new ListView(
                            children: list,
                          );

                          // return _buidlExpnsionListTile(snapshot.data[0]);
                           /*List<AuditAreas> auditAreaList = snapshot.data[index].auditAreas;
                           print('@@ audit area list size == ${auditAreaList.length}');
                          return Text('Screen index == '+index.toString());*/
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                else{
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )
```

Please help me out..

Comment: Show us some piece of code plz

Comment: @RodrigoBastos Okay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initialize it:

```
TextEditingController controller;
```

On initState:

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = new TextEditingController();
  }
```

Controller example in TextFormField:

```
new TextFormField(
                validator: (senha) =>
                    senha.isEmpty ? 'Por favor insira sua senha' : null,
                onSaved: (senha) => _pass = senha,
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.vpn_key,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  filled: true,
                  hintText: 'Senha',
                ),
                controller: controller,
              ),
```

To access the TextFormField text just make `controller.text`

Comment: I have EditFields created dynamically based on server response inside ExpansionTile. 

how do I add TextFieldController dynamically and get all values upon button click? Please help me out..

Comment: I am also looking for how to dynamically get the controller value

to add the controller dynamically just do:
`nameFields.add (TextEditingController (text: name));`

Comment: Can you please guide me how to implement this?
`nameFields.add (TextEditingController (text: name));`

Comment: I'm confused, why did you mark an answer that didn't help your dynamic problem? This answer is for non-dynamic field, and there is no relation with `nameFields`, so I have no idea why this could be an answer.